# Proof that $VaR_c(L)=(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{c+1}2))^2$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, finance, chi-squared, risk-assessment

> The loss $L$ has the $\lambda_1^2$ distribution, i.e. the distribution
> of the random variable $X^2$, where $X$ has a standard normal
> distribution. Proof that $VaR_c(L)=(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{c+1}2))^2$, where
> $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal
> distribution.
>
> Edit: definition $VaR_c(L)$ is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk#Mathematical_definition

My try: $$VaR_c(L)=F_L^{-1}(c)$$ $$F_L(t)=\mathbb P(L\le t)=\mathbb P(X^2 \le t) =\mathbb P(-\sqrt t \le X \le \sqrt t) = F_X(\sqrt t)-F_X(-\sqrt t)=\Phi(\sqrt t)-\Phi(-\sqrt t)$$

However I don't know what I can do to finish my task.

Comment: What is $\textrm{VaR}_c(L)$?

Comment: @callculus42 $VaR_c(L)$ is value at risk for $L$ - loss distribution and level $c \in (0,1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236249/how-to-proof-that-phi1-1-phi-1-for-standard-normal-distribution?noredirect=1) $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ so $F(x)=2\Phi(\sqrt{x})-1$. We conclude: $2\Phi(\sqrt{x})-1=u\implies x=(\Phi^{-1}((1+u)/2))^2$.